# Any way to distinguish `obj[x, y]` from `obj[(x, y)]`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I want to implement a class that holds nested data. I would like to implement `__getitem__` in a way so that `obj[x][y]` can be abbreviated by `obj[x, y]`.

However, I noticed a problem: The signature of `__getitem__` is that it expects a single positional argument instead of `*args`. If multiple arguments are given, they are automatically put into a tuple.

I.e. `obj[a, b]` and `obj[(a, b)]` both appear to be equivalent to `obj.__getitem__((a,b))`

But then how can I distinguish the two cases

1. The outer layer is indexed by tuples and `obj[(a, b)]` should return the value at that index
2. The outer layer is not indexed by tuples and `obj[a, b]` should return `obj[a][b]`

The only possible solutions I am aware of currently are

1. Abandon the idea of coercing `obj[x, y]` into `obj[x][y]`
2. If we only want `obj[x]` always write `obj[x,]` instead.

Both are not really satisfactory.

Comment: Is `isinstance` the way to go ?

Comment: @KrisI thought about that, but it does not seem to be easy if the code should be agnostic about what kind of objects are used to index the outer/inner layer.

Comment: `obj[(a, b),]` ?

Comment: @iacob that is precisely solution (2) that I outline in the post, but I do not find it satisfatory, and would rather fall back on abandoning `obj[x,y]` if there is no better alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of trying to inspect the calling source code (which is extremely fragile, with all sorts of failure cases, nowhere near worth the instability and debugging headache), this is not possible.

`obj[a, b]` and `obj[(a, b)]` mean exactly the same thing in Python. There is no semantic difference, no difference in how they are executed, and nothing to hook into to distinguish them. It'd be like trying to distinguish the whitespace in `obj[a,b]` and `obj[a, b]`.

Comment: That is really unfortunate. I wonder why python doesn't at least allow a custom implementation of `__getitem__` with a signature of `__getitem__(self, *items)` instead of `__getitem__(self, item)`

Comment: @Hyperplane: There are all sorts of things the dev team *could* do to `__getitem__` - for example, allowing keyword arguments and `obj[x=y]` - but those things don't provide enough benefit in concrete use cases to be worth the extra complexity. (They might provide *some* benefit, but not *enough* to be worth complicating the language.)